# Use of the info parameter in Hybrid Public Key Encryption

Tags: key-derivation, hkdf

I dont understand the use of the info parameter, what does "to fold in identity information" mean? What is the security benefit?

> All the algorithms also take an info parameter that can be used to influence the generation of keys (e.g., to fold in identity information) [...]

https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-irtf-cfrg-hpke-07.html#name-hybrid-public-key-encryptio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I dont understand the use of the info parameter, what does "to fold in identity information" mean?

It essentially is context information; that is, protection so that the ciphertext can't be reused in a different context.

Here is a simple example; suppose I encrypt a message to you, and fgrieu intercepts it.  Now, what fgrieu could do is forward that message to you and claim it was from him (he can't read it, however because I wrote it, he knows it must be good :-)

If that's all the system did, he'd succeed; there is no way that the message wasn't from fgrieu.

However, if we were to routinely put the sender's name in the info field ("poncho" in this case), well, fgrieu's attack wouldn't work - the only way you can decrypt the email is to include "poncho" in the info field during decryption, and you know that the specific email came from me (or some other poncho).

Comment: Oh, new bad person fgrieu :)

Comment: It sound a bite like *additional authenticated data (AAD)* in e.g. AES-GCM.

Comment: @hdev: quite a lot like the AAD in AEADs (or the tweak in FPE)